# Degrees of freedom

Tags: vector-spaces

Grateful if someone could tell me whether my rationale is correct:

If I impose $m$ constraints on $\mathbb R^n$ (where $n<\infty$), then the set has $n-m$ degrees of freedom. Hence this subspace has dimension $n-m$.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you impose $m$ ***linear*** and ***linearly independent*** constraints on $\mathbb R^n$, then the set has the dimension $n-m$. The vector space of these $m$ constraints has the dimension $m$.

If only $k, k \le m$ (and not more) of these constraints are linearly independent, then the subspace of the constraints has the dimension $k$ and the orthogonal subspace has the dimension $n-k$.

Comment: Thanks, Jiri. What happens if the constraints are non-linear?

Comment: I was already typing ...

Comment: @russell How do you define the dimension of a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ which isn't a subspace?